# access image using Authorize filter .net core

Tags: security, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I need to show an Image using an `<img src="">` tag. I am storing my files in a statics folders

using **asp.net core 3.1 Web api** to access image location,

The issue is that once I got the Image path using the api, anyone can directly access the image without using any access token.

How can I restrict an Image path with a access token ?

Answer (score 0):

To protect files, you need to apply authorization to the request. Microsoft suggests using a controller action for this. Example [from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#static-file-authorization):

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult BannerImage()
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(
        _env.ContentRootPath, "MyStaticFiles", "images", "red-rose.jpg");

    return PhysicalFile(filePath, "image/jpeg");
}
```